# Why does my ATSP function using dynamic programming enters infinite loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Global variables:

```
int verNum = 0, minimum = INT_MAX;
double st;
```

Initializing function in main

```
ATSP(graph, visited, start, 0);
```

Where:

```
vector<vector<double>> graph; -> contains costs of travels
vector<bool> visited;         -> has the size equal to the number of cities
int start = (rand() % verNum);-> random starting point
0                             -> starting cost (before any travel)
```

Function:

```
void ATSP(vector<vector<double>> graph, vector<bool> visited, int start, int cost) {

    visited[start] = true;

    if (find(begin(visited), end(visited), false) == end(visited)) {
        cost += graph[start][st];
        if (cost < minimum)
            minimum = cost;

        return;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < verNum; i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                cost += graph[start][i];
                start = i;
                ATSP(graph, visited, start, cost);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
        
        vector<vector<double>> graph;
        //this is where i insert data into the graph

        //this is the place where i check how big the graph is
        //and assign that value to verNum variable 

        vector<bool> visited;
        visited.reserve(verNum);
        for (int j = 0; j < verNum; j++) visited.push_back(false);

        int start = (rand() % verNum);
        st = start;



        ATSP(graph, visited, start, 0);


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, it just loops infinitely. My guess is, it has something to do with my vector visited, but i'm not sure what the problem really is.

As ***kiner_shah*** advised, i wrote an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int verNum = 0, minimum = INT_MAX;
double st;

void ATSP(vector<vector<double>>& graph, vector<bool>& visited, int start, int cost);

int main() {

    verNum = 4;

    vector<vector<double>> graph;
    //               a   b   c   d
    vector<double> a{0, 12, 42, 56};    graph.push_back(a);
    vector<double> b{78, 0, 40, 15};    graph.push_back(b);
    vector<double> c{20, 34, 0, 13};    graph.push_back(c);
    vector<double> d{27, 30, 22, 0};    graph.push_back(d);


    //printing out graph

    for (auto &it1 : graph) {
        for (auto &it2: it1)
            cout << it2 << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    vector<bool> visited;
    visited.reserve(verNum);
    for (int j = 0; j < verNum; j++) visited.push_back(false);


    //część kodu wykonująca ATSP
    int start = (rand() % verNum);
    st = start;
    cout << "\n" << st << endl;




    ATSP(graph, visited, start, 0);


    printf("Minimal cost equals: %d\n", minimum);




    return 0;
}


void ATSP(vector<vector<double>>& graph, vector<bool>& visited, int start, int cost) {

    visited[start] = true;

    if (find(begin(visited), end(visited), false) == end(visited)) {
        cost += graph[start][st];
        if (cost < minimum)
            minimum = cost;

        return;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < verNum; i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                cost += graph[start][i];
                start = i;
                ATSP(graph, visited, start, cost);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

***EDIT:***

after i added ***&*** to the void ATSP(vector<vector>***&*** graph, vector***&*** visited, int start, int cost) like ***kiner_shah*** advised, the program started working, Thank You All for help!!!

Comment: Can you edit your question with enough code so we can reproduce your problem? I am unable to replicate the infinite looping with your given function

Comment: so i added main function, but i cannot add graph becouse i fetch it from xml file using xml  parser, but it should work just fine with a random graph

Comment: I think you should pass vectors to the function by reference like `void ATSP(vector<vector<double>>& graph, vector<bool>& visited, int start, int cost)`. Currently you are passing by value (copying entire vector). You are checking `if (!visited[i])` in a loop, but after recursive function call, the values are not updated because you modify a copy of visited.

Comment: BTW, please post a [mre]. Just include some sample inputs in your code to `graph`.

Comment: That code doesn't enter an infinite loop when I tried it on godbolt.org. It said minimal cost equals 92. So, either you're doing something different or the graph data is the difference. You'll have to rework that then.

Comment: @22eragon22, what is the problem statement for this code?

Comment: Ah, sorry! i was a little late with updating status of the question, but the code works now. I added edit explaining what i changed. Thanks for help <3

Comment: tho i can only accept my own answer in two days, becouse i can't mark comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs works now, read ***EDIT*** for more info.